# Detecting Windows ID of logged-in user in RIA

Tags: wcf-ria-services

What is the best way to detect the current user Windows ID (on a corporate LAN on a Windows machine) in RIA?
I assume I should use WindowsAuth for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config file, set the authentication mode to "Windows". Also, in your client (assuming you're using the Business Application Template), you'll need to set webContext.Authentication to a new instance of WindowsAuthentication in App.xaml.cs.

Comment: i did not use the BAT. I used WindowsIdentity in the domain service to get the username.